# How can I split a Form file to Code and Designer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my project I have some forms and controls that have been created with an older version of Visual Studio. Is there a way to split them into the standard Code and Designer classes so that all the generated code is in the Designer file? Thanks.